# Number of nodes of a unoriented graph

Tags: graph-theory

If the adjacency matrix of an unoriented graph contains twice as more $0$s as $1$s what could the number of nodes possibly be?

One solution is $12$, but I do not understand how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an adjacency matrix, there are $n$ zeros on the diagonal, $\binom{n}{2}$ entries above the diagonal and $\binom{n}{2}$ below.  For every $1$ or $0$ above the diagonal, there is a corresponding $1$ or $0$ below (because of symmetry).  If there are $e$ edges, then there are $2e$ 1's in the matrix and $n^2-2e$ 0's.  You want to find $n$ and $e$ pairs such that $n^2-2e = 2(2e)=4e$.  This can be re-arranged to say $n^2 = 6e$.  So there are certainly some divisibility conditions to satisfy... otherwise, there should be many possibilities.